# "Vendor" vs. "vender" in Standard American English

Tags: word-choice, american-english, orthography, agent-noun-suffix

Which one is preferred?

I've always thought that *vendor* was the only spelling. The question was brought up by a typo, which the Word spellchecker did not correct.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The spelling *vendor* is the standard spelling. *The New Yorker*, as part of its bizarre house style, uses the spelling *vender*. No one else does, besides those trying to emulate *The New Yorker’s* style.

Of the [45 examples in COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=10598852), only 17 were actual uses of the spelling *vender* outside of *The New Yorker* (compared with over 2000 examples of *vendor*, a ratio of over 100 to 1). Two were proper names, eleven were from *The New Yorker*, and fifteen were in foreign languages.

Comment: That's New Yoikers for you

Answer (score 6):

These two words mean the same thing but actually have different etymologies:

> [Vendor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vendor) 1585–95; < Anglo-French vendo ( u ) r  < Latin venditor.
>
> [Vender](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=vender&searchmode=none) Origin: 1590–1600; vend + -er The word [vend](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vend) coming from:< Latin vendere  to sell, contraction of vēnum  (or vēnō ) dare  to offer for sale;

"Vendor" is preferred, but there is nothing wrong with "vender"

Answer (score 6):

This is perhaps the definitive answer: [scientific data from Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vender%2Cvendor&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image: Google NGram]

Answer (score -3):

I would submit that, as with normal "er" and "or" use (used for person and thing, respectively), the following use could make sense: vender is the person, the seller; vendor is the institution, the business, the shop.
Don't know, just applying logic to it all...

Comment: I can only think of cases where the *-er* and *-or* versions are alternative spellings (as in *jailer* and *jailor*) or refer to entirely different concepts (like *senser* and *sensor*). Can you provide examples to back up your theory of agent/agency?

Comment: @choster Going through a British word list, I find the following pairs: *abetter adjuster adviser better canter caster censer compacter conjurer conveyer correcter directer doer fer imposter jailer kroner lesser miner mortgager prier protester resister tenser vender* (with their *-or* counterpart). Going through this list, I concur: either they are different words altogether or they are variant spellings unrelated to the meaning. I see no person/thing distinction.

Comment: Be careful applying logic to language.

Comment: "er" and "or" aren't normally used for person and thing. That pattern is an exception, not a rule.

Answer (score -4):

I too, believe that  the expression of the word vender is more to the noun person,rather than  place or thing and the  word vendor more Latin in its origin ,for its same meaning , however there is possession in it  for place or thing .I could see how you can say vender is person and vendor as thing or place! just saying!!!  by the way my name is greek and it means 
of nobility , so we aristocrats get to do this , this being making judgment calls lol
Also....here is a sentence to express my above comment.

Patricia a vender I know went to visit many venues and vendors today in planing a show for 2015.
        So you can see how to use the word correctly and not have it look so duplicated and     without meaning. Each word can then stand on its own and have  its own meaning with out duplication.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Please take a moment to find upvoted answers to see the type of answer this site is looking for. We also provide [help on answering questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).